# Insert the rating after clicking the submit button using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to insert my rating form to the DB based up on click         submitform button but I am getting the following error.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No overload for 'sendbtnSubmit' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

#### kgis.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="kgis.aspx.cs" Inherits="portal.kgis" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <style>
    .ratingStar
            {
                font-size: 0pt;
                width: 13px;
                height: 12px;          
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
            .filledStar
            {
                background-image: url(images/Filled_Star.png);
            }
            .emptyStar
            {
                background-image: url(images/Empty_Star.png);
            }
            .savedStar
            {
                background-image: url(images/Saved_Star.png);
            }
            .auto-style1 {
                height: 50px;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
     <div id="popupContact">
                    <!-- Contact Us Form -->
                    <form action="#" id="feed" method="post" name="form" runat="server">

                        <h2>FeedBack</h2>
                        <hr />
                         <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">  </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>




                        <table style="width: 60%;">

                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 1px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 12px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="please can anyone help me on this i want to to store the rating to databse after clicking submit (onclick) form..server" Text="E-Mail"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" forecolor="red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="Input valid email!"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 28px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Area"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="drop1">
                                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlfields">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="gui">GUI</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="coc">Correctness Of Content</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="sug">Suggestions</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="new">New Requirements</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem T Value="efs">Existing Functionality Status</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 28px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Category"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="drop">
                                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cate">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="Hostel">Hostel </asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="School">School</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="Backwardclass">Backwardclass</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Feedback"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="msg" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Rating"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedStar"
                                        FilledStarCssClass="filledStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyStar" AutoPostBack="true"  MaxRating="5"
                        onchange="Rating1_Changed"                >
                                    </asp:Rating>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_point" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" OnClick="sendbtnSubmit" Text="Send" />

         </form>
                </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

#### kgis.aspx.cs

```
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
  namespace portal
    {
        public partial class kgis : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            protected void sendbtnSubmit(object sender,AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
            {
     string connectionString = "Server=KSRSAC-G2G\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Registration;Uid=sa;Pwd=SA#123;";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Registration].[dbo].[FeedBack] (Name,Emailid,Category,Feedback,Area,Rate) VALUES (@Name, @Emailid,@Category,@Feedback,@Area,@Rate)");
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailid", email.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", cate.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Feedback", msg.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Area", ddlfields.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", e.Value.ToString());
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
    }
    protected void Rating1_Changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
            {
                lbl_point.Text = "You rated " + e.Value.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

I want to to store the rating to database after clicking submit form using asp.net C#.

Comment: Do not use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`, see [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements) for why not. Also use the correct type when adding your parameter. I doubt `Emailid` or `Rate` are strings and if they are maybe you should rethink your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

`protected void sendbtnSubmit(object sender,AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)`

To:

`protected void sendbtnSubmit(object sender,EventArgs e)`

EDIT:

For second problem you said in comments, You have 2 options :

1- work with database in Rating1_Changed event.(Not recomended)

2- in sendbtnSubmit event, instead of using  `e.Value.ToString()`, use this 
 `myabe Rating1.CurrentRating.ToString()`

Comment: i changed but am getting error near this line: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", e.Value.ToString()); system.eventArgs does not conatin definition for Value

Comment: @user2882173 Well it says what is it. eventArgs Doesnt have value property (or Field). i EDITED ANSWER

Answer (score 0):

Write your code as below:

You are not using AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs in your code, so it's not clear where that comes in.

```
protected void sendbtnSubmit(object sender,EventArgs e)
            {
     string connectionString = "Server=KSRSAC-G2G\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Registration;Uid=sa;Pwd=SA#123;";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Registration].[dbo].[FeedBack] (Name,Emailid,Category,Feedback,Area,Rate) VALUES (@Name, @Emailid,@Category,@Feedback,@Area,@Rate)");
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailid", email.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", cate.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Feedback", msg.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Area", ddlfields.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", e.Value.ToString());
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
    }
    protected void Rating1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                lbl_point.Text = "You rated " + e.Value.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: if i change that line to  protected void Rating1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)am getting error like system.eventArgs does not conatin definition for Value( in this line cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", e.Value.ToString()); how to pass parameter here